# filling javascript object "on the fly"

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI, i have an object: var myobject = new Object;
and i want to dynamically fill it with properties while looping through jquery input collection in that manner:

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    myobject.$(this).attr('name') = $(this).val();
});
```

what i'm doing wrong here?
thanks in advance

Comment: missing semicolon? after val()

Comment: semicolon does not matter there.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.test').each(function () {
    var e = $(this);
    myobject[e.attr('name')] = e.val();
});
```

Objects in JavaScript can be accessed using `object.property` or `object['property']` (these two are equivalent). The latter allows you to use expressions (like variables): `object[propertyName]`.

Comment: @alega: You can accept the answer that fits best by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it.

Comment: This answer is not efficient because of the two $(this) inside of the function. Using $() is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

With the way you are doing it:

```
var myObject = {};
$('.test').each(
    function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        myObject[elem.attr('name')] = elem.val();
    }
);
```